# Quand utiliser « maximal » et « maximum » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, mathématiques

Comme mentionné dans le titre, quand utiliser « maximal » et « maximum » ?

Comment: est-ce que le tag «mathématiques» veut dire que la question porte sur le jargon mathématique?

Comment: Plus ou moins, car les notations max/sup, min/inf existent dans les mathématiques.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dans l'usage courant, on peut utiliser *maximum* comme nom ou comme adjectif. Le mot *maximal* est exclusivement un adjectif, et la langue soutenue a tendance à le préférer. Il n'y a en général pas de différence de sens entre *maximum* et *maximal*.

Le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, dans sa 8<sup>e</sup> édition (1932), classe *[maximum](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/maximum)* seulement comme substantif, mais cite des usages en apposition où le nom ressemble à un adjectif, tel que « tarif maximum ». La 9<sup>e</sup> édition (1992) admet *[maximum](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/maximum)* comme adjectif, tout en émettant l'avis que « à *Maximum* employé adjectivement on préfèrera l'adjectif *Maximal* ».

J'ai l'impression qu'il y a dans certains cas une nuance de sens entre *maximum* employé comme adjectif et *maximal*, entre « le plus élevé parmi un ensemble fixé de possibilités » et « que l'on cherche à rendre aussi élevé que possible ». (Les exemples sont ce que j'écris spontanément)

> C'est l'heure de pointe, nous allons payer le tarif maximal [ou maximum]. [Il y a trois tarifs suivant l'heure.]
>   Ce sont des clients riches, il faut leur faire payer le tarif maximum. [Il faut fixer un tarif très élevé.]

Il en est de même pour *minimum* et *minimal*. Il existe aussi une paire *optimum/optimal* (*optimum* est rarement utilisé comme adjectif) ainsi que *extrêmum/extrêmal* (rare en dehors des mathématiques).

---

En mathématiques, *maximum* et *maximal* peuvent avoir un sens différent. Le *maximum* d'un ensemble ordonné est un élément qui est plus grand que tous les autres (il n'y en a qu'un, sauf à généraliser aux préordres) ; un *élément maximal* est un élément tel qu'il n'en existe pas de plus grand (il peut y en avoir plusieurs). Un maximum est toujours maximal, mais le contraire est faux en général (si l'ordre n'est pas total). Par exemple, dans un ensemble à trois éléments avec a < b et a < c, b et c sont tous deux maximaux mais il n'y a pas de maximum.

Comment: Je partage l'impression, mais il me semble que les deux exemples sont inversés (a priori les tarifs sont fixés et on ne peut pas payer plus qu'à l'heure de pointe, et les riches je leur ferais payer *un* tarif *maximal* on peut toujours essayer de l'augmenter un peu, il n'y a pas de (tarif) *maximum*.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Vu que nous avons des impressions contraires, la nuance doit être purement imaginaire.

Comment: Ah zut, j'osais espérer que c'était une inversion involontaire. :-)

Comment: Je reste sur ma pensée, *maximiser* c'est *rendre maximal*, car *rendre maximum* ne plait pas du tout à mon oreille (sauf pour des maths).

Comment: Tiens la nomenclature mathématique conforte ma théorie: la définition de « élément maxim*al* » en math c'est on ne peut pas trouver plus grand (ce que tu exprimais par « aussi élevé que possible »), Alors qu'un maximum c'est un élément tel que tous les autres sont plus petits. Remarque: la raison est peut-être simplement que ça évite les ambiguïtés.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je confirme, dans mes définitions, a est un élément maximal c'est si a≤b, alors a=b, et un maximum c'est pour tout b, b≤a.

Comment: A noter que dans une ensemble totalement ordonné, les notions de maximum (ou plus grand élément) et d'élément maximal coïncident.

Comment: @rds En français, *ensemble* est masculin. (Et j'avais déjà indiqué ce cas particulier dans ma réponse.)

Answer (score 4):

À strictement parler, *maximal* est un adjectif alors que *maximum* est un substantif. Par extension, ce dernier est aussi utilisé dans les locutions adverbiales.

Le *Grand Robert* considère *maximum* comme nom et adjectif, mais renvoie à *maximal* sous la sous-entrée d'adjectif.

[Termium](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=1644.html#zz1625) offre les suggestions suivantes :

> On emploie les adjectifs maximal, minimal et optimal de préférence à maximum, minimum et optimum : Une hauteur maximale (plutôt que une hauteur maximum). Le pluriel s’écrit comme celui des adjectifs en « -al » : maximaux, minimaux, optimaux (masc. plur); maximales, minimales, optimales (fém. plur.) : les prix minimaux, les températures maximales, les conditions optimales. Maxima est aussi attesté comme adjectif féminin : Une hauteur maxima.
>
> Légère nuance : le minimum de veut dire « le moins possible de » : Vous devez prendre le minimum de risques, alors qu’un minimum de équivaut à « une quantité minimale de » : Vous pouvez quand même prendre un minimum de risques. Réussir à un examen avec un minimum de points pour obtenir la note de passage.

En emploi courant, *maximum* s'utilise comme nom et adjectif ainsi que dans les locutions adverbiales, et *maximal* ne s'emploie que comme adjectif.

Answer (score 1):

En tant que nom ou adverbe, seul *maximum* est valide.

Cependant, en tant qu'adjectif, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de règle bien définie, juste une forme qui sonnera peut-être plus juste que l'autre selon les cas.